# preconfiguring WIFI SSID and password in AOSP build 9 and above

Tags: android, android-source, android-wifi

How to place SSID and password in AOSP before build
so that the device will automatically get connected to preconfigured wifi after flashing the rom into the device

for Android 7 and 8, we can add the credentials into wpa_supplicant_overlay.conf file
Is there any way for android 9 and above

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now being called [Wi-Fi Easy Connect](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-easy-connect) ...in [`wpa_supplicant/android.config`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/refs/heads/master/wpa_supplicant/android.config#536):

```
# Easy Connect (Device Provisioning Protocol - DPP R1 & R2)
CONFIG_DPP=y
CONFIG_DPP2=y
```

The documentation misses `CONFIG_DPP2` ...

Set `update_config=1` to enable the use of tools, alike in [`wpa_supplicant_template.conf`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/refs/heads/master/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_template.conf).
One still can configure just any network. as shown in the example [`wpa_supplicant.conf`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/refs/heads/master/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf#1681).

The specification: https://www.wi-fi.org/file/wi-fi-easy-connect-specification

Comment: so placing the SSID and psk in wpa_supplicant.conf and setting update_config=1 in wpa_supplicant.conf file will help right ?